# Heroku Facebook App Breaking on First PHP Call

Tags: php, html, facebook, heroku

I'm having an issue with my Heroku Facebook application (PHP app). It seems like the app loads up to my first PHP call that I have in part of the opening JavaScript of my application. This app doesn't break on my desktop but did, until switching it out of sandbox mode, break  on my laptop. It now works on my laptop but not on anyone else's computer. Here is what I see (note this is within the  tags):

```
var xxxxxx;
  (function(d, t) {
    var s = d.createElement(t), options = {
    'userName':'userName', 
    'formHash':'xxxxxx', 
    'autoResize':true,
    'height':'563',
    'async':true,
    'header':'show', 
    'ssl':true,
    'defaultValues':'field1=<?php echo he(idx($basic, "first_name")); ?>&field2=<?php echo he(idx($basic, "last_name")); ?>&field3=<?php echo he(idx($basic, "email")); ?>&field7=<?php echo $basic["hometown"]["name"]; ?>&field6=<?php echo $basic["location"]["name"]; ?>'
    };
    s.src = ('https:' == d.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'wufoo.com/scripts/embed/form.js';
    s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var rs = this.readyState; if (rs) if (rs != 'complete') if (rs != 'loaded') return;
    try {
      z7p9m3 = new WufooForm();
      z7p9m3.initialize(options);
      z7p9m3.display(); 
    } catch (e) {}
  };
    var scr = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], par = scr.parentNode; par.insertBefore(s, scr);
  }) (document, 'script');
```

However, when **someone else** loads the app (even when they are flagged as a developer) the app breaks and stops loading content here:

```
var xxxxxx;
  (function(d, t) {
    var s = d.createElement(t), options = {
    'userName':'userName', 
    'formHash':'xxxxxx', 
    'autoResize':true,
    'height':'563',
    'async':true,
    'header':'show', 
    'ssl':true,
    'defaultValues':'field1=
```

You can see that the file breaks on that first PHP call that's supposed to auto-populate the form. I'm not sure why this is happening, the only tips that I've seen similar to my issue tell me to take the app  out of sandbox mode (which I did). Here's a link to the app: https://apps.facebook.com/flgwaptest/ . Any help would be greatly appreciated, this seems to be an odd problem that I haven't been able to find a solution for.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out a while back and forgot to post. The short version is that (for whatever reason) the browser was having a problem with the quotations and way I was accessing the data. Technically speaking, I was able to access what I was trying to and it would work for me but not others. Here's the fix:

```
'defaultValues':'field1=<?php echo he(idx($basic, "first_name")); ?>&field2=<?php echo he(idx($basic, "last_name")); ?>&field3=<?php echo he(idx($basic, "email")); ?>&field7=<?php echo $basic["hometown"]["name"]; ?>&field6=<?php echo $basic["location"]["name"]; ?>'
```

That line was the problem, instead of trying to access the values in-line I declared variables earlier and just echoed out those. It looks like this:

```
'defaultValues':'field1=<?php echo $fName; ?>&field2=<?php echo $lName; ?>&field3=<?php echo $email; ?>&field7=<?php echo $hometown; ?>&field6=<?php echo $location; ?>'
```

As you can see, I removed any possible '/" confusion on the browser's part, this seemed to fix the problem.